# 401 error by replying to actionable message in outlook desktop client

Tags: azure, office365, azure-logic-apps, adaptive-cards, actionable-notification

I have developed an Azure logic app and Azure function to send actionable messages to users.
On the bottom are two buttons to reply to another logic app. If I test it on the outlook web app (O365 E3-E5 licensing), it works fine.
On the outlook desktop app it's not working with Error 401 not authenticated.
The logic app is not triggerd if I check the history logs.

Any ideas what causes the error or how to debug?

Best regards

Edit:
The Logic App uses an HTTP trigger with a specific json input.
In the Logic App the users JWT Token will be checked with an Azure Function. But, the logic app never shows an run started if I click on send in the outlook desktop app. It looks like the call is blocked by the outlook client.

Comment: Hi theface, could you please provide some more details of your problem ? Such as the screenshot of your logic app. Do you use a trigger in your logic app ? Which trigger did you use ?

Comment: Hi, I added some information.
Important to know is that the Logic App never starts when i click on submit in the actionable message rendered in outlook desktop clients. It's only possible in the Outlook web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution or a workaround...

Instead of triggering the Logic App directly, the request is sent to an Azure function (which also authenticates the user). The function is just a "middleman" that forwards the request to the logic app after successful authentication.

I don't know why it doesn't work with Logic Apps in this particular version of the Outlook desktop application... but with Azure functions there is a solution :)

Comment: I'm also facing this problem, could you share some more information?  I'd like to know how this "middleman“ authentication setup?  Is that use function key or Microsoft Identity platform? Thank you.